# Remove urls from list that contains specific substring in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring, list-comprehension

I would like to remove urls, which don't match an certain keyword from a given list. This means, I would like to remove all urls which contain 'sale' or 'new" in my case.

**Test data**

```
url_list = ['https://www.test.com/men-fashion/', 'https://www.test.com/men-shirts', 'https://www.test.com/sale-fashion/', 'https://www.test.com/new-fashion/']
```

My sub-strings are the following:

```
to_remove = ['sale','new']
```

I have tried to do so by using an list comprehension in combination using any(), but this filter out all urls matching my "to_remove"-list. But what I'm expecting is the opposite result.

```
url_list[:] = [url for url in url_list if any(substring in url for substring in to_remove)]
print(url_list)
```

Comment: `all(substring not in url ...`, then?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach using regex:

```
import re
url_list = ['https://www.test.com/men-fashion/', 'https://www.test.com/men-shirts', 'https://www.test.com/sale-fashion/', 'https://www.test.com/new-fashion/']
to_remove = ['sale','new']

result = [i for i in url_list if not re.search("|".join(to_remove), i)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.test.com/men-fashion/', 'https://www.test.com/men-shirts']
```